# How to pivot dataframe by columns from compound index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe represents time series. it has three columns: ts, code, count
I try to pivot it.

```py
# set index by code, ts to get
# code_01 1  
# code_01 2
# ...
# code_42 1
# code_42 2
df_count = df[['code', 'count', 'ts']]
df_count = df_count.set_index(['code', 'ts'])

# fails with KeyError: 'ts'
df_pivot = df_count.pivot(index='ts', values='count', columns='code')
```

I've duplicated columns ts, code

```
df_count['ts_pivot'] = df_count['ts']
df_count['code_pivot'] = df_count['code']
df_pivot = df_count.pivot(index='ts_pivot', values='count', columns='code_pivot')
```

Is there more elegant solution?

Comment: any chance of a reproducible input? :-)

Comment: also a desired output would be great too

Comment: Why not simple: `df.pivot(index='ts', values='count', columns='code')`? and maybe chain with `stack()`?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to `set_index(['code', 'ts'])` if you're going to `pivot`, then rather `unstack`.

Comment: df_pivot = df_count.unstack(level='code')['count'] ?